# Is the visits/day counter on Area51 working well?

Tags: bug

Each time I go on the ["Esperanto Language" Area51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95499/esperanto-language), the visits/day counter indicates 0 or 1 visit. I guess there are more people who visit the website.

Is it a bug? Someone has an idea? How is it possible to correct that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a bug. See [Traffic (views, visits) isn't correctly registered on Site Analytics or Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308966/traffic-views-visits-isnt-correctly-registered-on-site-analytics-or-area-51) where an employee says

> We're investigating, we've had a number of large changes to our Google Analytics infrastructure, looks like we missed some bits..